Multiplicative Pairing functions
I'm looking into invertible pairing functions $P: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} $ that have some multiplicative properties in at least one argument.
The properties i'm looking for are:
$P(x_1, y_1) = z_1$
$P(x_2, y_2) = z_2$
with
$ z_1*z_2 = P(x_1, y_1) * P(x_2, y_2) = P(x_3, y_1 * y_2)$
If such function does not exist then I'm open to explore pairing functions with alternative properties.
Context:
I'm researching holomorphic encryption schemes. Goal is to develop a scheme that allows aritmetic operations over an encrypted message (aka cyphertext).
Example of a multiplicative encryption scheme is RSA where you can
$ rsa(m_1 * m_2) = rsa(m_1) * rsa(m_2) $
This is useful because it allows to perform multiplications without the need of decrypting the individual messages $m_i preserving annonymity.
However RSA doesn't preserve annonymity in the sense that the cyphertext can be correlated to original message. For example in a voting system one could distinguish wheter two messages are identical.
A workaround is to introduce non-determinism eg. via a pairing function and a random number:
$ rsa( P(r, m) ) $

How about $P(x,y) = y^n$ for some natural number $n$?

Also, what relation does $x_3$ have with $x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2$? Do you only want that an $x_3$ like this exists?

hah almost, your function is not bijective and hence not invertible.
I require the exsistance of P^-1(z) = (x, y).
re $x_3$: I don't require any specific relationships on $x_3$

Ah, sorry. I missed the word "invertible".

While my answer below is correct, there may be a clearer way to formulate the ideas. Here is an attempt at a more conceptual answer. I am assuming that zero is not a natural number. Results shouldn't change much, however, if the converse is assumed.
For a function $P$ like you described one can define the sets $M_y = P(\mathbb N, y) \subseteq \mathbb N$. As $P$ is bijective, they provide a partition of $\mathbb N$ into (countably) infinite subsets. The multiplicativity condition exactly states that for $z \in M_y$ and $z' \in M_{y'}$ we have $zz' \in M_{yy'}$. Conversely, if $(M_y)_{y \in \mathbb N}$ is a partition of $\mathbb N$ into infinite subsets, we can construct a $P$ out of it: Choose bijections $c_y \colon \mathbb N \to M_y$ for all $y$. Then $P(x,y) = c_y(x)$ does the trick.
This proves that up to choosing the bijections, a function $P$ is the same as a multiplicative partition of $\mathbb N$ into infinitely many infinite subsets. Because of the multiplicative property, such a partition is completely determined by deciding which subset the primes land in. Thus, all we need is a function $r$ from the set of prime numbers to the naturals, namely the one such that $p \in M_{r(p)}$. What properties does $r$ need to have such that all $M_y$ are infinite?
First of all, $1$ needs to be in the image. Otherwise, $M_1 = \{1\}$ is finite. Secondly, every prime $p$ must be hit, as well. Otherwise $M_p$ is empty since the the multiplicative extension of $r$ does not hit $p$ either. $p$ is prime after all, so trying to hit it with a product doesn't help. These two conditions actually suffice to make all $M_y$ infinite. If $q_p$ is any prime such that $r(q_p) = p$ for $p$ prime or $1$, we can exhibit infinitely many elements mapped to $y  = \prod_p p^{v_p}$. Namely, the $q_1^n\prod_p {q_p}^{v_p}$ for $n \in \mathbb N$ will do.
Now choose any map from the primes numbers to the naturals such that $1$ and all primes are in the image, and we're done. Such a map surely exists as the primes and the naturals are equinumerous, so we can choose a bijection between them.

Functions like this do exist. Here is how to construct them (all of them, I think):
Choose any function $r$ from the set of prime numbers to $\mathbb{N}$ such that $1$ and all prime numbers are hit. Multiplicatively extend $r$ to
$$
\hat r \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N, \prod_{p \text{ prime}}p^{v_p} \mapsto \prod_{p \text{ prime}}r(p)^{v_p}.
$$
Then $\hat r^{-1}(n)$ is non-empty for all $n$. In order to see this, factor $n$, choose an element of $r^{-1}(p)$ for all prime factors $p$ of $n$ and multiply them up with the correct multiplicities. Moreover, the fibres $\hat r^{-1}(n)$ are countably infinite. This is because there is a prime number $q$ with $r(q) = 1$. If $\hat r(x) = n$, then $\hat r(q^k x) = n$ for all $k$.
Now choose bijections $c_n \colon \hat r^{-1}(n) \to \mathbb N$. Define $Q \colon \mathbb N \to \mathbb N \times \mathbb N, m \mapsto (c_{\hat r(m)}(m), \hat r(m))$. Then $Q$ is bijective and its inverse is a function $P$ as in your question.
For a concrete example, given a prime $p$ let $p^+$ be the smallest prime larger than $p$ and $p^-$ the largest prime less than $p$, if $p$ is odd. Set $2^- = 1$. The choice $r(p) = p^-$ and $c_n$ the unique monotonous bijections then yields $P(x,y) = 2^{x-1}\prod_{p \text{ odd prime}}(p^+)^{v_p(y)}$, where $v_p(y)$ is the multiplicity of $p$ as a factor of $y$.
